# Wordpress and custom web application under the same public folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-applications

I have developed a web custom application in PHP and the files are in the public folder of the server! Also, I have `.htaccess` file for this custom application... The application I have developed is running for "fake" subdomains: For example.. john.site.com, mary.site.com, george.site.com but all the subdomains are running from the files that are under the public folder.

Now I want to install a WordPress for the main domain, site.com. The WordPress files I want to install in one folder inside of the public folder so as not to confuse with the files of a custom application. How can I achieve that?

In short:
Application files: under the public folder
Wordpress site: under publick_folder>wordpress_folder

Wordpress site: site.com
Application : *site.com

The htacess file of applications is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex site/ index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^control_panel/ /index.php [L,QSA]
### incomes ###
RewriteRule ^incomes/view/(.*)$ /incomes/view.php?hash=$1 [B,PT]
```

Comment: Hi @george kal! Please would you share your .htaccess file?

Comment: I added in the post!